# how to close jquery Lity using .close()?

Tags: jquery

I am using Lity as the popup form, but I could not close the popup using the .close() API, afterwards. How can I close, the Lity popup, by calling the .close() API, with the 'close' button? Thank you in advance!

```js
$('a').on('click',function(){lity('#lity').opener();});
$('button').on('click',function(){
  //do something
  lity('#lity').close(); //this is not working
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lity/2.3.0/lity.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lity/2.3.0/lity.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">surprise</a>
<div id='lity' class='lity-hide'><button type='button'>close</button></div>
```

Comment: https://sorgalla.com/lity/

Answer (score 2):

Since no one answers, finally found 2 solutions after days of struggle. 1st solution is using a global variable 'myLity' and assign to the 'myLity' when opening the Lity. Then close the Lity using the same 'myLity' global variable.

```js
var myLity=null;
$('a').on('click',function(){
  myLity=lity('#lity');
  myLity.opener();
});
$('button').on('click',function(){
  //do something
  myLity.close(); //this is not working
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lity/2.3.0/lity.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lity/2.3.0/lity.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">surprise</a>
<div id='lity' class='lity-hide'><button type='button'>close</button></div>
```

The 2nd solution is even simpler, just adding the 'data-lity-close' attribute to the close button.  And no need of global variable.  Thanks anyway

```js
$('a').on('click',function(){lity('#lity').opener();});
$('button').on('click',function(){
  //do something
  alert('executed');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lity/2.3.0/lity.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lity/2.3.0/lity.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">surprise</a>
<div id='lity' class='lity-hide'><button type='button' data-lity-close>close</button></div>
```

Comment: It should be noted that these solutions don't work when you use lity to open an iFrame